# How to listen for click on Angular 2 element and get the event object?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a directive which I will apply on certain anchor elements to `preventDefault()`.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[myDirective]'
})
export class myDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('click') onClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault() // event is undefined
  }

}
```

What I'm trying to do is basically this in jQuery:

```
$('[my-directive]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

How can I achieve this in angular? I have Angular 4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the `args`, too:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myDirective]'
})
export class MyDirective {
  @HostListener('click', ['$event']) /* note args array */
  onClick(event) {
    console.log(event);
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Check out an example Plunkr: https://embed.plnkr.co/eNXEdb/ (open the console then click on *"Hello Angular"*).

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` doesn't seem to be working. And it is a `MouseEvent`. How can I stop the page change?

Comment: @Jeff yes it's a `MouseEvent`, you *clicked* on it. What are you trying to prevent? I've updated the Plunkr to show preventing an `a` click causing navigation, for example.

Comment: Got it. I had the `routerLink` directive before my custom directive and that was taking precedence as a result. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Correction: Having the `routerLink` directive overrides it anyways regardless of order.